# How to scrape web data in vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have followed jsotola's suggestion and recorded the following macro, but encountered an error, how can I solve it?
Run time error 91 and the following code has been highlighted

Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh

```
Sub Macro1()
     ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="1-1-1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""http://www.hkjc.com/English/racing/Horse.asp?HorseNo=V099""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="1-1-2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""http://www.hkjc.com/English/racing/Horse.asp?HorseNo=V099""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Source{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table 0", _
        "Connection to the 'Table 0' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table 0" _
        , """Table 0""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table 1", _
        "Connection to the 'Table 1' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table 1" _
        , """Table 1""", 6, True, False
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: your code works. what is your question?? what are you trying to scrape??

Comment: The description you provided is not enough to bring the clarity of what data you are after. Try to be specific so that you can have a sharp and effective answer. Thanks.

Comment: you said that `The above vba code did work properly` ... so why are you trying other code?

Comment: All I want is to scrape ALL the target web data into Sheets(1).range("A1"). The first code scrape nothing. The second code only open the target website with IE

Comment: i just recorded a macro of creating a new data connection to a web page and loading the data into a worksheet, from the website that you  mentioned in your question, and it displayed correctly.... you can do the same  ... it is in `data` tab ... new query .... other sources .... from web

Comment: Hi jsotola, I have followed your suggestion and recorded the following macro, but encountered an error, please see the edited question above, thank you very much

Comment: @Yung Lin Ma, did you mean the table data from that page?

Comment: It will be better if you show me a screenshot of that specific part you wanna scrape so that I can help you with that.

Comment: Hi Shahin, Ideally I want to scrape ALL data within the weblink, I will do more vba work on finding what I really want. Now, I have run time error on scrape it into sheets(1).range("A1")

Comment: As you can see, if the scraping table needs specified table's name, it should be "Table 0" and "Table 1" that I want to scrape only

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhhohkb4s85lyr1/horse_stuff.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Hi Shahin, please see the edited question with image, that is what I want to scrape, "SmartBoy", "V076", "Country of Origin", "Color", "Sex" ... ...

Comment: Not the picture you uploaded to dropbox, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following script.

① I grab the left hand side links with

```
.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).getElementsByTagName("a")
```

As these return relative paths starting with "about:", I replace this part with the fixed prefix string `BASESTRING`. This gives the [absolute path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

② I target the table with main info by getting get a collection of the `table` tags and selecting the appropriate table by index.

```
Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(6)
```

③ Additionally, as targeting by className is not supported with method I am using, due to late bound HTMLfile I assume), I parse the sub header out "SMART BOY (V076)" from the innerHTML of  an element containing this info. Otherwise, it could have been targeted more cleanly with `.getElementsByClassName("subsubheader")(0)`

---

**Example data on page:**

[image: Example data]

---

**Example output from code:**

[image: Output from code]

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, hTable As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V076", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "HEAD"))

    With CreateObject("htmlFile")
        .Write sResponse
        Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(6)
        Dim links As Object, title As String
        Set links = .getElementsByTagName("table")(3).getElementsByTagName("a")
        title = Replace$(Split(Split(.getElementsByTagName("table")(2).innerHTML, "title_eng_text>")(1), "<")(0), "&nbsp;", vbNullString)
    End With

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, hBody As Object
    Set hBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")

    Const BASESTRING As String = "http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/"

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = title
        r = 2
        For Each tSection In hBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                c = 1
                .Cells(r, c) = links(r - 1).innerHTML
                .Cells(r, c + 1) = Replace$(links(r - 1), "about:", BASESTRING)
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(r, c + 2).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
                r = r + 1
            Next tr
        Next tSection
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```